# Comentário que virou Resposta

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro

Lembro de ter lido no Meta.SO que tinha uma maneira de burlar a suspensão de publicar respostas. Será que foi isso que aconteceu aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25344/terminal-command-that-automatically-stops-a-program ?

> [image: comentário que virou resposta]

Comment: O OP que fez o comentario virar uma resposta entao?

Comment: Acho que foi no meta.so e não no meta.se, mas não tou encontrando a referência... @LucasVirgili, não, acho que é um bug. Você está 100% certo de que postou um comentário, né?

Comment: Sim, sem duvidas! Nao postaria uma resposta tao useless :P

Comment: Ele postou um comentário, eu li, era um comentário. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe nenhuma maneira de um comment ser convertido numa resposta. Nós por vezes auto-convertemos respostas em comentários (quando a resposta é somente um link para outra questão no mesmo site), mas uma conversão na direção oposta não existe no nosso código.

Lamento dizer, o mais provável é que o Lucas tenha acidentalmente inserido esse comentário na caixa errada. Converti agora a resposta em comentário, assim agora está onde deveria estar :)

> **Versão original:**
>
> (With apologies for responding in English... I hope someone can edit this to translate on my behalf. My Portuguese is non-existent.)
>
> There's no way for an comment to be converted to an answer. We sometimes auto-convert *answers* to *comments* (when the answer is basically just a link to another question on the same site), but the conversion in the other direction doesn't exist anywhere in our code.
>
> Sorry to say, it's most likely that Luke accidentally typed his comment in the wrong box. I converted the answer to a comment, so now it's where it belongs. :)

Comment: Oh well, sorry if I made that :( It was really not my intention.

Comment: @LucasVirgili No worries, it happens. :)

Comment: @Sergio Thanks!

Comment: And now? An comment has been converted to an answer, no one will search for the reason?

Comment: @Patrick Sorry, what do you mean? Nothing was converted to an answer in this case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was converted to an answer, I've seen his comment, it was a comment. o.O I think something gets really wrong around here. Well bugs happens, it should be one.

Comment: @Patrick I can dig deeper, but as far as I know, there is no code that would convert a comment to an answer. It doesn't exist. When did you see his comment as a comment? (Keep in mind that *right now* it is a comment - I moved his answer to the comment section.)

Comment: I've seen the question, no comments or answers was there, some minutes after this, Lucas Virgili's comment was posted.